# No error message: scipy odeint - spyder ("Kernel died, restarting")

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, spyder, odeint

I'm using scipys odeint for a simulation. After a change in my code I got the error message "Kernel died, restarting" again and again. The problem was that odeint got a zero time interval. I needed a lot of time to determine the problem.

I am not sure if that is a odeint or Spyder problem, but there should be an appropriate error message.

Could this be a problem in my package constellation?

Running a minimal working example with the same problem in the command prompt I just get nothing.

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
t = np.linspace(0,0,10)
def func(x):
    return x**2
sol = odeint(func, [1.], t)
print(sol)
```

Win 10, 64-bit, Python 3.6, SciPy 1.0.0

Comment: Can you run your script outside of spyder (e.g. open up a terminal/command prompt and run the script with the `python` command)?  Does it work then?  (If you do that, be sure that the `python` command in the terminal is the same one that spyder uses.  I don't use spyder, so I don't know how you would check where its `python` command is.)

Comment: That usually corresponds to a segmentation fault can you try it in the command prompt

Comment: Running a minimal working example with the same problem in the command prompt I just get nothing.
     
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
t = np.linspace(0,0,10)
def func(x):
    return x**2
sol = odeint(func, [1.], t)
print(sol)

Comment: edit your question instead

Comment: Note that `odeint` is not recommended to be used. You should use `solve_ivp` instead. This is not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: @xaav Thanks for the hint. I will change my code.